# В модуле pytesseract не выводит текст с картинки

Tags: python, pytesseract

[image: вот код]

Короче, я хочу, чтобы чтобы код принимал координаты курсора и из этих двух координат получается прямоугольник. Нужно, чтобы код выводил текст с этого скриншота, но он почему-то говорит, что для данной операции нужно больше прав(Я пишу код с администратора). Путь к `Tesseract-OCR` указал - не работает.

```py
from coordinats import x1, y1, x2, y2
import time 
import numpy as np
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import cv2
import os
import pytesseract

filename = 'Image.png'
x = 1
last_time = time.time()

while True:
    screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox = (x1, y1, x2, y2)))
    print(f'Loop took {time.time() - last_time}')
    last_time = time.time()
    cv2.imshow('window', cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    cv2.imwrite(filename, screen)
    x += 1
    print(x)
    if x == 2:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

img = cv2.imread('Image.png')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\777\AppData\Local\tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-5.3.0.20221222.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для того, чтоб вам ответили нужно разместить картинку в вопросе, код наоборот вставить текстом, ограниченным тремя апострофами для сохранения форматирования. Чтоб его можно было скопировать и вставить для проверки. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая ошибка.Советую скопировать репозиторий с проектом pytesseract, командой
git clone https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
и
pip install pypiwin32